# Linear program feasible region is infinite with optimum solution of bounded cost

Tags: linear-programming

Is there an example of linear program in two variables that has infinite feasible region with an optimum solution of bounded cost?

Comment: What if the objective function is identically equals to zero, no matter what feasible solution is ...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Yes. One possible way is to think of how to make $(0,0)$ the optimal point if the feasible region is the first quadrant. That is think of one such objective function.

Comment: max x-2y

subject to x-y<= 1

x,y >= 0

is that correct?

Comment: $$x-2y=(x-y)-y \leq 0,$$ hence that works. congrats.

Alternative solutions include $\min x $ subject to $x, y \geq 0$ or $\min x+y $ subject to $x, y \geq 0$ or even as suggested as Ashkan, just let the objective function be a constant.

Comment: Thank you @Siong Thye Goh

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider the following linear program:
$$\text{maximize } 5x+3y$$
$$5x-2y \geq 0$$
$$x+y \leq 7$$
$$x \leq 5$$
$$x,y \geq 0$$

**The feasible region:**

[image: The feasible region]

As you can see the feasible region is bounded by the following half spaces: $5x-2y \geq 0$, $x+y \leq 7$, $x \leq 5$ and $x,y \geq 0$

Taking out $x+y \leq 7$ and ($5x-2y \geq 0$ or $x \leq 5$) from the system of linear inequalities gives an infinite feasible region with the pair $(0,0)$ as a minimum feasible solution. Thus turning the initial problem to a minimum linear program and taking out $x+y \leq 7$ and ($5x-2y \geq 0$ or $x \leq 5$) will give a linear program in two variables that has infinite feasible region with an optimum solution of bounded cost.